# Any method/algorithm for finding this pattern?

Tags: algorithm

I am new to machine learning, so I figure I should just ask you guys for suggestions. My problem is basically to find users with similar patterns. For example, there are 3 users A, B and C, and each user has 4 features, F1, F2, F3, F4 for each day. Let's assume the following values for these features:
Day 1

USER F1  F2  F3   F4

A    10  20  10   50

B    2   4   2    10

C    2   3   9    13

Day 2
......

What I want to identify is that USER A & B have 100% match (ratio for each feature is always 5. assume for each of these 5 days this ratio is a constant), while A & C or B & C have a match score between 0.00 and 1.00. What algorithms will work for me? 
I thought about cosine similarity, correlations calculations, etc.. But since I don't have many data points (5 days * 4 = 20 values), I don't know if this is valid?

Comment: What is "match score" ?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity shows that it will be 1.0 for A and B (or, generally, any two vectors where one is a multiple of the other) but not for A,C and B,C - and you should be able to check this by hand.

Because you only have a small number of vectors it should be possible to compute and check all the similarities. If you had a very large number of vectors you could look for approximate methods that work with cosine similarity, such as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing#Random_projection.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a machine learning algorithm, what you need is a way to see the similarity of 2 vectors. The most common way if to use a quadratic difference. If your data has a similar range this would work correctly. This means that your data is in the same range, something like (0-10). If you have some values like 0.0001 and others like 10000 then you'll need other methods.

Another good method is [Kullback-Liebler](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence). Here you have to convert your data into a probability. All the rows had to sum 1.